# Automatically updating created/updated date field on the entity in dropwizard hibernate

Tags: hibernate, event-listener, dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard Hibernate ( hibernate 4) to persist some simple entities.

My entities have some attributes like "created_date", "modified_date" and "deleted_date".
I would like these properties to get automatically populated/updated on save/update time.
And I want to have that logic on the ORM level not on the DB. Also, on the other hand, for some solid reasons, we are managing our own sessions.

Now the problem is that dropwizard does not support full capabilities of the hibernate 4.  It ignores the `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate`.
 So I decided to write my own custom `SaveOrUpdateEventListener` and register it in the EventListener Registry in the sessionFacotry. Then I realized that Dropwizard does provide access to the EventListener Registry. So went into the dropwizard `SessionFactoryFactory` class and modified it to get access to the EventListener registry. 
 then using the following code I am trying to register my event listener:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = hibernate.getSessionFactory();
EventListenerRegistry listenerRegistry = sessionFactory.getSessionFactoryOptions().getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
EventListenerGroup<SaveOrUpdateEventListener> evlg = listenerRegistry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.SAVE_UPDATE);
evlg.appendListener(new SaveOrUpdateDateListener());
```

and here is my event listener:

```
public class SaveOrUpdateDateListener extends DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SaveOrUpdateDateListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) throws HibernateException{
        logger.info("onSaveOrUpdate is being called");
        if (event.getObject() instanceof LastModifiable) {
            LastModifiable record = (LastModifiable) event.getObject();
            record.setCreatedDate(Instant.now());
        }
        super.onSaveOrUpdate(event);
     }
}
```

and this is my entity class:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(value = { SaveOrUpdateDateListener.class })
@Table (name = "portfolio")
public class PortfolioBusiness implements LastModifiable, Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private long id; 

    @Column(name = "org_id", nullable = false)
    private long orgId; 

    @Column(name = "subscription_id", nullable = false)
    private String subscriptionId;

    @Column(name="duns", nullable = false)
    private int duns; 

    @Column(name="created_by", nullable = false)
    private long createdBy;

    @Column(name="created_date", nullable = false)
    @Convert(converter = InstantPersistenceConverter.class)
    private Instant createdDate; 

    .
    .
    .
}
```

and here is the superclass of my entity class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(value = { SaveOrUpdateDateListener.class })
public interface LastModifiable{
    public void setCreatedDate(Instant instant);
}
```

When I print out the list of the registered event listeners I see my eventlistener there. howevern when I try to save or update the entity my eventlistener is not being called at all. it only calls the default event listener.
I have already seen this 
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9381

so I was also wondering if any one has any example of the solution proposed in the above link working with Dropwizard.

Answer (score 4):

We were able to get `@PrePersist` and `@PostPersist` working using Interceptors:

```
public class DateTimeInterceptor {

    @PrePersist
    public void onPrePersist(Object entity) {
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void onPreUpdate(Object entity) {
    }
}
```

Register the Interceptor in Entity:

```
@EntityListeners(value = {DateTimeInterceptor.class, PostInterceptor.class})
```

But the most **important** part is you need to add a custom configuration file:

```
/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator
```

Which contains a single line:

```
org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator
```

The Dropwizard version is 0.8.1. Try it out and hope this helps

Comment: Audience: for the above changes to work please add hibernate-entitymanager in your pom or gradle.

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate 5.3 (Dropwizard 1.1) I had to tweak [yunspace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30043205/507761) fairly significantly, but it was a great starting point.  The main issue was that `JpaIntegrator` seems to have been removed, so I had to implement my own integrator:

```
public class EntityIntegrator implements Integrator {
    @Override
    public void integrate(final Metadata metadata,
                          final SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
                          final SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        final EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry = serviceRegistry.getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);

        eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.PRE_UPDATE, EventListener.class);
        eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.PRE_INSERT, EventListener.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void disintegrate(final SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
                             final SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        // no-op
    }
}
```

Then in `/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator`:

```java
your.package.here.EntityIntegrator
```

And finally, implement the `EventListener` class referenced in the integrator:

```java
public class EventListener implements PreUpdateEventListener, PreInsertEventListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreInsert(final PreInsertEvent event) {
        // your logic here
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onPreUpdate(final PreUpdateEvent event) {
        // your logic here
    }
}
```